# How to look at an existing merge-commit in a 3 way diff tool

Tags: mercurial

I am interested in looking at this commit:

```
[Sep-26 16:14]$ hg log --rev 4b47cc6d212d
changeset:   186413:4b47cc6d212d
parent:      186412:108068f9c1c6
parent:      185155:3452a331b240
summary:     merge master to jakeFeatureBranch
```

As you can see this is a merge.  I would like to open this merge in my 3-way-diff tool to see how conflicts were resolved.  How can I do this?

I tried running `hg bcompare -c 4b47cc6d212d` but my difftool is just launched with two files.

When I am doing a merge my diff tool will open in 3 way merge mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly more robust version:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

MERGE_REV=$1
FILE_NAME=$2

echo "Replaying merge ${MERGE_REV} for file ${FILE_NAME}"
hg log --rev "${MERGE_REV}"

echo "Extracting key revisions"
PARENT_REV_1=$(HGPLAIN= hg log --rev "${MERGE_REV}"^1 --template '{node|short}')
PARENT_REV_2=$(HGPLAIN= hg log --rev "${MERGE_REV}"^2 --template '{node|short}')

if [ -z "${PARENT_REV_2}" ];
then
    echo "Abort: ${MERGE_REV} is not a merge revision"
    exit 1
fi

BASE_REV=$(HGPLAIN= hg log -r "max(ancestor("${PARENT_REV_1}", "${PARENT_REV_2}"))" --template '{node|short}\n')

echo "Merge Commit: ${MERGE_REV}"
echo "Parent 1:     ${PARENT_REV_1}"
echo "Parent 2:     ${PARENT_REV_2}"
echo "Base:         ${BASE_REV}"

TMP_DIR=$(mktemp --directory --tmpdir replaymerge.XXXX)
echo "writing to ${TMP_DIR}"

MERGE_RESULT="${TMP_DIR}"/merge-result
PARENT_1="${TMP_DIR}"/parent-1
PARENT_2="${TMP_DIR}"/parent-2
BASE_FILE="${TMP_DIR}"/base-file

hg cat --rev "${MERGE_REV}"    "${FILE_NAME}" > "${MERGE_RESULT}"
hg cat --rev "${PARENT_REV_1}" "${FILE_NAME}" > "${PARENT_1}"
hg cat --rev "${PARENT_REV_2}" "${FILE_NAME}" > "${PARENT_2}"
hg cat --rev "${BASE_REV}"     "${FILE_NAME}" > "${BASE_FILE}"

echo "Retry the 3-way merge"

# Replace with your diff tool here.
# WARNING: some diff tools accept a different ordering for the file
# panes, and will not put the contents of your 4th file into their 4th
# window. They only use that for saving, not reading.
bcompare "${PARENT_1}" "${PARENT_2}" "${BASE_FILE}" "${MERGE_RESULT}" || true

rm -rf "${TMP_DIR}"
```

- extracts the revisions without using `grep`/`sed`/`head`/`tail` (uses native mercurial templating)
- deletes the temporary files
- detects non-merge revisions

Comment: Haven't run this but I like the removal of the grep/sed/head/tail.  Going to mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

mergeCommit=$1
file=$2

echo "Replaying this merge"
hg log --rev $mergeCommit

echo "Extracting key revisions and writting to /tmp"
parent1=$(hg log --rev $mergeCommit | grep 'parent' | head -n1 | sed 's_.*:__')
parent2=$(hg log --rev $mergeCommit | grep 'parent' | tail -n1 | sed 's_.*:__')
base=$(hg log -r "max(ancestor($parent1, $parent2))" | grep 'changeset' | tail -n1 | sed 's_.*:__')

echo "Merge Commit: $mergeCommit"
echo "Parent 1:     $parent1"
echo "Parent 2:     $parent2"
echo "Base:         $base"

actualMergeResult=/tmp/actualMerge
correctMergeResult=/tmp/correctMerge

parent1File=/tmp/parent1
parent2File=/tmp/parent2
baseFile=/tmp/base

hg cat --rev "$mergeCommit" "$file" > "$actualMergeResult"
hg cat --rev "$parent1" "$file" > "$parent1File"
hg cat --rev "$parent2"  "$file" > "$parent2File"
hg cat --rev "$base" "$file" > "$baseFile"

echo "Retry the 3-way merge"

# Replace with your diff tool here.  WARNING: some diff tools will
# not put the contents of your 4th file into their 4th window.  They
# only use that for saving, not reading.  
bcompare $parent1File $parent2File $baseFile $correctMerge || true
```